# Тернарная условная операция в запросе Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Хочу составить запрос типа:

```
var articles = db.Articles.Where(SectionId == 0 ? (не знаю как написать тут чтобы выбралось 10 последних значений) : a => a.SectionId == SectionId);
```

Возможно ли использовать тернарную операцию в запросе? или составлять конструкцию if..else?

Comment: составлять конструкцию

Чтобы вывелось 10 последних значений, надо сначала вызвать OrderBy, затем Take

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Я бы делал это как то так, поправьте, если сильно не прав
var articles = (SectionId == 0)
      ? ( from art in db.Acticles  select art).OrderBy(art.xxx).Take(10)
      : ( from art in db.Acticles where art.SectionId == SectionId select art)
```

Comment: orderby тоже в запросе можно указать (внутри скобочек, я имею ввиду)